# Where does "getent group A" get the information on group A?

Tags: linux, ldap

I have some questions about `getent group`.

1. Where does `getent group A` get the information on group A?
2. Does it only get it from `/etc/group`?
3. Is it possible that I can find a user (belonging to group A) by `getent group A` while I can *not* find the user from group A in `/etc/group`? If yes, how could this happen?

The third one is actually the problem I met.

Example:

```
1st. [root@*** test]# getent group A | grep A

2nd. [root@*** test]# cat $INSTALLROOT/etc/group | grep A
```

I can find a user `a` from the first command while I cannot find the user `a` from the second command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where does "getent group A" get the information on group A?

It is configured in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. `man getent` tells this.

> Does it only get from /etc/group?

It depends on your config files. On my machine it does not get this information only from /etc/group since it is configured in this way:

```
group:      files ldap
```

> is it possible that i can find a user (belong group A) by "getent group A" while can NOT find the user from group A in /etc/group?

Yes it is possible if there are at least two sources of data for groups.
By the way, take a look at how `getent group` work - run it under strace.

```
strace -s 256 -o getent.strace.txt -v getent group
```

And see what system calls it does. In my case it first reade from /etc/group and loads an ldap module and starts reading from socket

Comment: Thanks skwllsp and it makes sense.